# How to check array value using in_array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an doubt. I want to check the new value is present in existing array which contains json data using PHP `in_array` method. I am explaining my code below.

```
{"introId":"582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9","introLabelName":"Age","isIntro":"Yes"}
```

Here i need to check `582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9` is present in the above array or not using PHP. Please help me.

Comment: IF your data is in JSON Format then you need to use `json_decode()` and then compare it with `in_array()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = '{"introId":"582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9","introLabelName":"Age","isIntro":"Yes"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo in_array('582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9', $array);
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpio.net/s/1gl6)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple way:

```
   $json_array = '{"introId":"582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9","introLabelName":"Age","isIntro":"Yes"}';
$newvalue = '582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9';

$json_newArr = json_decode($json_array, true); 

if(in_array($newvalue, $json_newArr)){
    echo 'True';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your given sample data is in JSON Format thats why you need to decode this using
[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then compare it with [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$jsonData = '{"introId":"582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9","introLabelName":"Age","isIntro":"Yes"}';

$decodeArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);

if (in_array('582aa53755f5ab487614ddc9', $decodeArray)) {
    echo 'Found';
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

Hope it should be solve your problem. Thank you.